# Setting up Salesforce HTTP Endpoint using Jitterbit

Tags: community, jitterbit

At the moment we are polling for any changes in Salesforce every 10 minutes or every hour depending on the operation. I want to essentially setup an HTTP Endpoint for Salesforce using Jitterbit. So whenever there are certain changes made in salesforce it would trigger a specific operation to run. How would I go about that since I don’t have a Url to put in when choosing the HTTP Endpoint operation in Jitterbit? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

**I got a response from Jitterbit, so I thought I would post for anyone in the future that has this question. Hope this helps!**

Jitterbit server is hosting a website that Salesforce is calling with an outbound message. That being the case it is critical to allow the call from Salesforce to the Jitterbit server as well as the confirmation call back to Salesforce through the firewall on the machine where the Jitterbit server resides. The ports that need to remain open are 46908 and 46909
The outbound message calls to the Jitterbit server. The workflow rule triggers the outbound message. 
When you edit and you want to send the account and all the contacts into a database, you can’t do that. An outbound message is for a single object. The method that you would have to use is to send the id field in the message into jitterbit and then query back into Salesforce to pull all the desired records. 
A workflow rule can apply to only one object in Salesforce

1. Login to Salesforce account
2. On the left hand side of the Salesforce page under “Build” select “Create”
3. Select “Workflows and Approvals” from the left hand side of the screen.
4. Select “Create and manage workflow rules”
5. Click the Continue button on the next page that loads
6. On the “All Workflow Rules” screen click the “New Rule” button
7. You will now be on the “Configure New Workflow” page

a.   In the dropdown box select the Salesforce object that you are going to be working with in Jitterbit then click the next button
b.  Name your workflow rule. It is best practice to include the name of the Salesforce object that the rule applies to in the rule name. 
c.  Take a look at the radio button list titled “Evaluation Criteria”. Unless a timed event is being used, one of the first two options should be selected. If synchronization is going to be used in your operation use the second “created, and every time it’s edited” option. If you need to create and not update the first option should be selected then the first “created” option should be selected
d.  The “Rule Criteria” section needs to be modified even if this rule needs to always be applied. To always apply this rule, select a field that will never be null and set it not equal to an empty string. Once all necessary information is input to this page click the “Save and  Next” button

8. Select “New Outbound Message” from the “Add Workflow Action” dropdown
9. Give your “New Outbound Message” a name. The “Unique Name” can be left as the name automatically generated unless another outbound message with the same unique name has been used before on your companies Salesforce account.
10. To obtain the “Endpoint URL”:
    a.   Open Jitterbit studio and open the project to include this outbound message from Salesforce, or create a new project.

b.  Right click on “Operations” and select “New Operation”.

c.   From the radio button list select “Hosted Web Service” and click continue.

d.  Right click in the light gray area inside the operation, but not on one of the objects and select “View Hosted Web Service URL”

e.  Enter the address of the machine that is hosting your Jitterbit server in the textbox “Server” then click the “Copy to Clipboard” button. Do not modify the “URL” text that is generated.

11. Return to Salesforce and paste the text from the clipboard into the textbox labeled “Endpoint URL”
12. Select the available fields that you want to use in your Jitterbit operation and add them to the selected fields. The primary key field will be selected automatically.
13. Click the “Save” button in the upper right hand corner of the screen then the “Done” button on the upper right hand corner of the next page
14. The next step is to download the WSDL file.
    a.  On the right hand side of the page click “Outbound Messages”
    b.  On the “Understanding Workflow” page click the “Continue” button
    c.  On the “All Outbound Messages” page click on the name of the rule that you have just created
    d.  In the upper portion of the next page click on the “Click for WSDL” link and save the XML to a location that is easy for you to remember. Before saving, be sure to change the file extension to .wsdl.
15. Return to Jitterbit Studio. Right click on “Web Service Methods” and select “New Web Service Method”
16. On the first step of the “Web Service Method Wizards” select the radio button “Select a local WSDL file” and enter the path for the WSDL that you downloaded from Salesforce or find it using the “Browse” button. Give your web service method a meaningful name and click the “Next>” button at the bottom
17. For a Salesforce outbound message operation nothing needs to be modified on the “Operation” step of this Wizard. Click “Next>”.
18. Nothing needs to be changed on the “Details” step. Click “Finish”
19. Close the “Web Service Methods” tab.
20. Drag your newly created Web Service Method into the “Web Service Call” area of your Hosted Web Service operation

At this point it is good to understand the function of the two transformations in this operation. The first transformation occurs when a message is received from Salesforce. This transformation is used to map account data.
The second transformation replies to Salesforce, communicating that you have received the record.

21. The second transformation is the most simple so we will begin there. Right click on the transformation on the right side of the operation and select “Create New Transformation”
22. In the Transformation Wizard give your transformation a meaningful name and set the Source to “(None)” then click the “Finish” button.
23. On the next screen to appear fully expand the file tree on the right side and double click on “[EV?] Ack (Boolean)”. The formula builder will pop-up. Type the word “true” (no quotes) between the  tags and click the “OK” button. Click save and close this transformation tab.
24. Right click on the transition on the left. It should be the only thing still left unmodified in this operation. Click new transformation
25. In the Wizard step “Name” give your transformation a meaningful name and select a target for the data that you are going to pull down from Salesforce. A database would be the ideal choice for this method of setting up an Outbound Message. Click the “Next>” button.
26. The next step is “Target”. Select an existing target set to a database that is configured for the Salesforce data that you are pulling down, or create a new target. Test your connection and click the “Next” button.
27. The “Table Selection” step is next.
    a.  Begin by clicking the “Download List of Tables” button.
    b.  From the “Available Tables” list, select the table into which you would like your data inserted then click the arrow in the middle of the screen to add it to “Selected Tables”. 
    c.  Click the “Next” button.
28. On the next step choose the radio button from the “Select an Insert/Update Mode:” list that fits your needs. Click the “Finish” button at the bottom of the screen.
29. The “Transformations” tab will open allowing you to create your mappings. After you create the mappings click the save icon and close the “Transformations” tab. You are now ready to deploy this project to the Jitterbit server.
30. Return to Salesforce and select Create-Workflow & Approvals-Outbound Messages from the menu on the left of the page. Click the “Activate” link beside the name of your Workflow Rule